# jQuery Validator with Error Summary Inside ASP.NET Update Panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, jquery-validate

I wonder if somebody could help me out with an issue which has been stressing me out for some time now.

I want to include jQuery validation and the error summary inside an update panel on my page. I have found however that when the error summary div is inside the update panel, following the first postback, the summary no longer displays - however jQuery is still validating the form and preventing postbacks when the conditions I have set are not met.

To clarify, I am experiencing the following:

1. First load of the page, attempt to submit the page without completing details -> post back is prevented and error summary is displayed as expected.
2. Complete the forename and surname field, click submit -> the page is correctly submitted to the server.
3. Now blank out either the forename or surname field and click submit -> the page does not postback to the server, however the error summary is not displayed to the user.
4. Complete the forename and surname field -> the page is correctly posted back

If you move the the error summary div (div `class="error-container"`) outside of the update panel the page works as expected. Unfortunately I am not able to do this with my design.

I wonder if anybody has experienced this issue, and whether you have found a work around?

To Recreate my issue you can use the following code:

**TestValidator.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TestValidator.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestValidator" %>
```

Forename:
                
                Surname:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    load();

                    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
                        load();
                    });

                });

                function load() {

                    $("#<%= Me.Page.Form.ClientId %>").validate({
                        errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('.error-container')),
                        wrapper: 'li'
                    });
                }

                function checkForm() {
                    return $("#<%= Me.Page.Form.ClientId %>").valid();
                }


            </script>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**TestValidator.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class TestValidator
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Me.btnSubmit.Text = "Submitted at: " & Now.ToString
End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I get my jQuery functions to run every page load inside my updatepanels:

```
// Attach our single function that will call all of the functions 
// we want to run OnLoad to the Sys.Application.add_load handler.

if (Sys != undefined && Sys.Application) { 
    Sys.Application.add_load(callOnLoadFunctions); 
} else { 
    window.onload = callOnLoadFunctions; 
}

function callOnLoadFunctions() {

    // Add all the functions to be called

    load();            // your method
    function1();       // some other function
    function2();       // another function

}
```

I put all my js at the bottom of the page, and this is usually referenced in an external js file right after my jQuery and plugins references.

Comment: Hi
Thank you for your reply, however this method presents the same issues :(.

Comment: Well, from here I would try using firebug and the console in Firefox to log out messages to test when things are firing?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't have my script inside my updatepanel ... I would put it at the bottom of your page after your </form> tag.